# Inverse and Series Connection - TransferFunctionModel

Tags: control-systems

I need to perform certain operations on individual transfer functions. As an example,

```
sys=StateSpaceModel[{sysA,sysB,sysC,sysD}];
Tfsys=TransferFunctionModel[sys,s];
```

Now I extract the required transfer functions, say $P_1$ and $P_2$

```
P1=SystemsModelExtract[Tfsys,{1},{1}];
P2=SystemsModelExtract[Tfsys,{1},{2}];
```

Now I want to perform an operation like $\Gamma=P_2 (P_1)^{-1}$. So I use

```
T=SystemsModelSeriesConnect[P2,Inverse[P1]];
```

This gives me an error saying *the first argument cannot be interpreted as a polynomial matrix in SystemsModelSeriesConnect[#1,#2]*

I have tried writing it as $P_2.Inverse[P_1]$ but I cannot make it accept the argument. Additionally, I would need to do a lot of *algebraic* operations with the TransferFunctionModel which not always can be done with commands like *SystemsModelSeriesConnect*,*SystemsModelParallelConnect*, etc.

As you would have guessed, I am not too adept with the syntax in Mathematica, so please bear with my questions.

Comment: Could you give an example for your system?

Comment: As far as I know, `Inverse[]` works only on square matrices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know, if this is what you want. But you might try this:

```
P1 = SystemsModelExtract[Tfsys, {1}, {1}]
P2 = SystemsModelExtract[Tfsys, {1}, {2}]

P3 = TransferFunctionModel[Inverse[P1[s]], s]

T = SystemsModelSeriesConnect[P2, P3]
```

**How I did get this:**

Documentation says:

> Inverse[m] gives the inverse of a square matrix m.

And because

```
someTF = TransferFunctionModel[1/s, s]
someTF^-1
```

gives

[image: transfer function]

where the first one is a transfer function model, but the second one is mixed. It's 1/*someTFmodel*.

You have to get the inner of your transfer function model, invert it, and put it back into a transfer function model.
Helpful for this is documentation's
[`TransferFunctionModel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransferFunctionModel.html) section "Properties & Relations":

[image: excerpt]

Comment: How did you know it...it doesnt show up in the documentation...Can you give me a reasoning or insight into solving such issues? I seem to get in these minor issues a lot

Comment: See my edit. Just click a bit around in the documentation, very often the solution is there, you just can't see it :)

Comment: Really appreciate the response...cheers!